# ActiveMQ Artemis Transport scheme not recognized [vm] error

Tags: activemq-artemis

I tried to run this code:

```java
EmbeddedActiveMQ server = new EmbeddedActiveMQ();
server.setConfiguration(new ConfigurationImpl()
        .setAcceptorConfigurations(singleton(new TransportConfiguration(
                InVMAcceptorFactory.class.getName())))
        .setPersistenceEnabled(false)
        .setSecurityEnabled(false));
server.start();

ConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://0");
Connection connection = cf.createConnection();
```

But I got this exception:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [vm]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:333)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:346)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:304)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:244)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.examples.jms.JmsTopicSample.main(JmsTopicSample.java:84)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [vm]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:28)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:185)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:331)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not find factory class for resource: META-INF/services/org/apache/activemq/transport/vm
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder$StandaloneObjectFactory.loadProperties(FactoryFinder.java:98)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder$StandaloneObjectFactory.create(FactoryFinder.java:60)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:148)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:182)
    ... 6 more
```

All I could find on the web suggested that I'm missing some dependency on the classpath, but none failed with the `vm` protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that I used a wrong import. I used:

```java
org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
```

but I should have used:

```java
org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
```

For some reason the `apache-artemis:2.10.1` includes dependency to `activemq-client` from activemq version 5, which includes the other class.

Answer (score 2):

If you run into this error and you're not using Apache Artemis, then make sure `activemq-broker` is on the classpath.